# Construct the Galois closure of $\mathbb{Q} \subset \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]2)$.

Tags: galois-theory

Construct the Galois closure of $\mathbb{Q} \subset \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]2)$.

I think the closure is M = $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]2, i)$. This is Galois over $\mathbb{Q}$ because it is the splitting field of the separable polynomial $x^4 - 2$. But how to show that $M$ is the smallest Galois extension?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key is that every irreducible polynomial with one root in a Galois extension splits in that extension.

So, let $K$ be any Galois extension containing a 4th root of $2$. Then $K$ has (by definition) a root of $x^4 - 2$ in it, so it has all of them; in particular it has $i\sqrt[4]{2}$ and $\sqrt[4]{2}$ and since it's a field it has $i$.

Comment: thanks! in general, to find the Galois closure, do we have to 'guess' what it is, and then verify it is the smallest Galois extension?

Comment: @eatfood  If you write down minimal polynomials for all the generators, then the Galois closure is always the splitting field of those polynomials, no guessing involved. But then I guess the question becomes, how do you want to express it? For instance in this case, you could instantly say "the galois closure is the splitting field of $x^4 - 2$" and this uniquely determines the field, but isn't that useful as a description (for instance, doesn't tell you the degree of the field extension). To give a "nice" description, some light "guessing" might be the fastest way.

Comment: i see, thanks for the explanation!!